# Unable to deploy functions to the Function App with Private Endpoints

Tags: azure-functions, azure-private-link

We set up a Vnet with two subnets: Private Subnet for private endpoints and Function Subnet for regional Vnet integration of the function app. The function app and its storage account use private endpoints to block public access. We also configured private DNS zones for both resources to enable DNS resolution in the private network. The functions are written in C# with .Net Core framework. We did a nslookup of the function app from the VM that return private IP addresses respectively and successfully. We created a Self Hosted agent in the same Vnet and subnet as the function app. We tried to deploy the resources with this agent but got an error. We checked the NSG rules for the PrivateSubnet and attached a screenshot. We could deploy the App Settings for the function app with the private endpoint but not the function itself. See the screenshot for the App Settings.
Service Principal have owner access.

**NSG Rules:**
[image]

**Function Ap seetings:**
[image]

**Error Message:**
[image]

Comment: We created a Self Hosted agent in the same Vnet and subnet as the function app. > Is microsoft.storage and microsoft.web service endpoint added to the self hosted agent?